# Scheduling Random Activity or Service

Tags: android-broadcast

I am trying to create a service that performs a specific task, let's say for simplicity a simple Toast Message and then schedules itself to run again at a random time in the future.

I am using an alarm manager with a time delay to run the first instance of the service.  The service then sets a new alarm for a broadcast that will trigger the service to run again.

The approach I have taken is the following:

1. Main Activity Sets up an Alarm to run a Broadcast at a specified interval
2. Broadcast is received and sets up a new alarm to run the broadcast again, and then runs the required service.
3. Required Service completes task and shuts itself down.

Could someone please provide advice on if this is a viable approach?

I can't seem to get the Broadcast to be received.

I have registered the receiver in my Manifest file:

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
             CustomAlarmManager am = new CustomAlarmManager(context);
             am.setNextSchedule((long) StaticMethod.getRandomTimeDelay());
        }
}
public class CustomAlarmManager extends Activity 
{
     public CustomAlarmManager(Context context) 
     {
          alarmMngr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          intent = new Intent(context, CustomReceiver.class);
          pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
     }
     setNextSchedule(long timeDelay)
     {
          alarmMngr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeDelay, pendingIntent);
     }
}

public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
     @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)    
        {
             Intent i = new Intent(context, CustomService.class);
             CustomAlarmManager am = new CustomAlarmManager(context);
             am.setNextSchedule((long) getRandomTimeDelay());   
             context.startService(i);
        }
}

public class CustomService extends Service 
{
     @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
        {
             displayToastMessage();
             stopService(intent);
        }
}
Manifest File:
<receiver android:name="packageName.CustomReceiver" android:enabled="true">
```